# Logical operators and bit manipulation in C

Tags: c++, c, computer-science, logical-operators

i am trying to do some exercises, but i'm stuck at this point, where i can't understand what's happening and can't find anything related to this particular matter (Found other things about logical operators, but still not enough)

**EDIT: Why the downvote, i was pretty explicit. There is no information regarding the type of X, but i assume is INT, the size is not described either, i thought i would discover that by doing the exercise.**

```
a) At least one bit of x is '1';
b) At least one bit of x is '0';
c) At least one bit at the Least Significant Byte of x , is '1';
d) At least one bit at the Least Significant Byte of x , is '0';
```

I have the solutions, but would be great to understand them

```
a) !!x  // What happens here? The '!' Usually is NOT in c

b) !!~x // Again, the '!' appears... The bitwise operand NOT is '~' and it makes the int one's complement, no further realization made unfortunately 

c) !!(x & 0xFF) // I've read that this is a bit mask, i think they take in consideration 4 bytes in X, and this applies a mask at the least significant byte?

d) !!(~x & 0xFF) // Well, at this point i'm lost ...
```

I would love not having to skip classes at college, but i work full time in order to pay the fees :( .

Comment: What's the type of `x`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307281/c-operator-is-a-two-not

Comment: Trust me, if there was any information on the type of X, i would put it. There isn't any information on that!

Comment: The answers would all be correct without the `!!`. That suggests you are omitting some of the quesiton text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add brackets around the separate operations and apply them in order. e.g.

```
!(!(~x))
```

i.e. !! is 2 NOT's

What happens to some value if you perform one NOT is:

If `x == 0` then `!x == 1`, otherwise `!x == 0`

So, if you would perform another NOT, you invert the truth-value again. i.e.

If `x == 0` then `!!x == 0`, otherwise `!!x == 1`

You could see it as getting your value between 0 and 1 in which 0 means: "no bit of x is '1'", and 1 means: "at least one bit of x is '1'".

Also, `x & 0xFF` takes the least significant byte of your variable. More thoroughly explained here:

[What does least significant byte mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16535335/what-does-least-significant-byte-mean)

Comment: I think the OP is confused about the double use of `!`. Maybe you should address that.

Comment: What happens when i use 2 NOTs? That's my doubt. Regarding the mask, i think i understand what happens with the operand '&'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming x is some `unsigned int/short/long`/... and you want conditions (if, while...):

a) You´ll have to know that just a value/variable as condition (without `a==b` or something)
is `false` if it is `0` and true if it is not `0`. So, if `x` is not `0` (`true`), one `!` will switch it to `0` and the other `!` to something not-0-like again (not necessarily the old value, only not 0). If `x` was `0`, the `!` will finally result in `0` again (first not `0`, then again `0`).
The whole value of `x` is not `0` if at least 1 bit is 1...

What you´re doing is to transform either 0 to 0 or a value with 1-bits to some value with 1-bits. Not wrong, but... You can just write `if(x)` instead of `if(!!x)`

b) `~` switches every `0`-bit to `1` and every `1` to `0`. Now you can search again a `1` because you want a `0` in the original value. The same !!-thing again...

c and d:
`&0xFF` sets all bits except for the lowest 8 ones (lowest byte) to `0`.
The result of `A&B` is a value where each bit is only `1` if the bits of A an B at the same position are both `1`. `0xff` (decimal 255) is the number which has exactly the lowest 8 bits set to `1`...